# Regex fix delimiters in a string

Tags: regex, perl

I have some strings of the following structure :
"H-e-l-o-world-guys", so some words are delimited wrongly. 
How can I delete those dashes only between single characters and not between words ?

I've tried this : `$words =~ s/-(.)//g;`

but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more complicated than you think, because you're trying to assert a negative case... but then "keep" that negative.

So to do this, you need look-around modifiers to your regex:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "H-e-l-o-world-guys";

$str =~ s/(?<=\w)-(\w)(?!\w)/$1/g;
print $str;
```

That regex breaks down as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "H-e-l-o-world-guys";

$str =~ s/(?<=\w)      #Preceeded by word char
            -(\w)      #dash, then word-char - capture word char (as $1)
           (?!\w)      #followed by non word char
           /$1/gx;     #put that word-char back
           
print $str;
```

Note - it won't anchor at start of line.

This turns your line into:

```
Helo-world-guys
```

Edit:

```
Բ-ա-ր-ե-ւ-world-guys
```

Is a slightly different scenario. `\w` won't match those letters by default, but if you add the `/u` flag to your regex, it should work once more.

From: [`perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> **/u**
>
> means to use Unicode rules when pattern matching. On ASCII platforms, this means that the code points between 128 and 255 take on their Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) meanings (which are the same as Unicode's). (Otherwise Perl considers their meanings to be undefined.) Thus, under this modifier, the ASCII platform effectively becomes a Unicode platform; and hence, for example, \w will match any of the more than 100_000 word characters in Unicode.

Or go for the expedient - `[^-]`:

```
$str =~ s/(?<=[^-])      #Preceeded by word char
            -([^-])      #dash, then word-char - capture non-dash char (as $1)
           (?![^-])      #followed by non word char
           /$1/gx;     #put that word-char back
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for unicode, like for this :
"Բ-ա-ր-ե-ւ-world-guys"

Comment: That's a rather different scenario, but try `/u` as a regex modifier. I think that should do the trick.

Comment: use utf8; helped. Thanks again